# How to Read and Compare string in a file then get the number/s beside it in C

Tags: c

This is the Algorithm:

1. Open the file.
2. Read a string from the file.
3. Compare the string.

   - If the string matches, get the number/s after '=', then exit the loop.
4. Check the end of the file.

   - If it's not yet the end of the file, go back to step 2.
   - If the end of the file is met exit the loop, and go to step 5.
5. The string is not in the file.

This is the program i made:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("Converter.txt", "r");
char a;

while( fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL ){
    if(strcmp(line,a)){
        printf("There is such string");
        sscanf(line,"%*[^=]=%f", &num);
        printf("\n\n%.2f",num);
    }else{
        printf("NULL\n");
        continue;
    }break;
}
```

inside of file:

```
Inch to Meter = 0.0254
Foot to Centimeter = 30.84
Foot to Inch = 12.00
and many more.
```

Input:

```
Foot to Centimeter
```

Output:

```
There is such string

30.84
```

The problem is it only scan the first line and it doesn't scan the number beside the string that it compares.

Thanks.

Comment: Example input and expected output?

Comment: Without seeing the input file (at least a reasonable number of lines), your declaration of `line` and where/how you initialize `'a'`, there is very little anyone can do but guess. You should also validate `fp` is in fact open before its use in `fgets`.  See: [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Ken: The `break` and `continue` are misused but do not cause the problem

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do this is to let sscanf do the string comparison for you:

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
    double num;
    if (sscanf(line, " string =%lf", &num) == 1) {
        printf("Found line with 'string' and %f\n", num);
        break; } }
```

sscanf will match the string `string` on the input line, followed by an `=` and a number.  Note also the spaces in the format string -- these will match any amount of whitespace, so this will match all of the following lines:

```
string=1
    string  =  2
string =4
```

Of course, it will also match lines like:

```
string=5with extra stuff on the end...
```

and ignore everything after the number.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the appropriate function to check that the `line` contains the string, instead of

```
if (strcmp(line,a))
```

use

```
if (strstr(line, a) != NULL)
```

you should know that `strcmp()` will not do a partial matching and that it actually returns `0` when there is a match, so in your case the condition is always being true, and since you don't check the return value of `scanf()` when it fails `num` will not be modified, leading either to undefined behavior, or to printing the previous value depending on whether there was a match before.

Do check the return value from `sscanf()` since ignoring it may cause problems.

And don't forget to check that the file was actually opened by `fopen()`, it returns `NULL` on failure.